# Custom UITableView Header set background colour fail

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView, and the tableview's background colour is white.

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

However, the section header's background always appears like gray. How can I remove the gray background??

[image]

Since I have override the drawRect func of the UITableView, so I want something to appear behind the header view.

I have tried the following:

a) Change the UITableView style to Grouped, the problem goes, but the header cannot glued on top of the table.

b) Use section header title instead of header view

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

the header's background is transparent, but I have multiple labels.

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Thanks to @Omkar, the correct way is set

```
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

Comment: Have you added a custom cell which acts as a header /footer view ? if yes then set the background colour of the custom cell to clear colour. Have you overridden viewForHeaderInSection Method?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot yes, I have override the viewForHeaderInSection method ,and create a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView, also I have set the background color to clear. It does not work. But change the content view's background color to other color works except clear.

Comment: Have you set the background color of the custom cell which acts as header/footer view to clear color?

Comment: I use self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor(). 
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() is deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the background colour of the content view to clear color and at the same time you also need to set the background color of the tableView cell to clear color. Place this in your viewForHeaderInSection method. You will then be able to see the color set to the tableView.

```
    YourCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    YourCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Please find the attached image for my code and also the table view whose style is plain style in storyboard. And i have also added the image of how it looks after running

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @Joe SHI were you able to achieve it? as i have implemented the same code and it works

Comment: No, I have already changed the table cell's background and content view's background to clear, otherwise I will not be able to see the line under the coloured dot. Are u sure you are using UITableViewPlain Style. If I changed to UITableViewGrouped, it works but the header not glued to the top

Comment: Yes i am using UItableViewPlain style. Do you want me to attach the code? for that i will have to again post an answer

Comment: It is highly appreciated if you can share the code.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the code to it  as an image

Comment: I have tried your way, it works. The difference between our code is I use 
    
    tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as UITableViewHeaderFooterView!

And I will post my code

Comment: You can use  this then  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as UITableViewCell!  . Do you want to use headerfooterview itself?

Comment: Yes, I want to use headerfooterview. Use UITableViewCell will cause an bug in my application. So it is better to use headerfooterview.

Comment: ok use this it works add this line  cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

Comment: i've discovered that, if all you want to do is display a table of items with no editing allowed or no other views added to the cell, you can get by with just:   
    YourCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()   -- you can leave out        YourCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Answer (score 0):

This is my ViewController code, the only difference is I use headerfootview subclass. I set the tableview's background to blue, and if i pull down a little bit, you will see there looks like a mask on header.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text  = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as UITableViewHeaderFooterView!

    cell!.textLabel?.text = "Header"
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: @omkar Guhilot, If I scroll to the bottom and scroll back. the mask disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the color to `.clear` is not solved the problem, you can change the `"tint"` color of the custom header view to clear too. It worked on me.[image]