# UITableViewHeaderFooterView contentView is not setting to transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a ViewController with a background image which as a TableVC as its subview. 
I want the table view to be transparent and have accomplished that, also the tableviewcell's are transparent. But I'm facing a difficulty in getting the tableviewheaderfooterview to be transparent, as when i set it's contentview backgroundcolor to clearColor - it shows a gray color.

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

```
private let collapsibleTableView : UITableView = {
   let tv = UITableView()
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
    tv.backgroundView = nil
    tv.separatorStyle = .None
    return tv
}()
```

Also, I've subclassed UITableViewHeaderFooterView to my custom class and where I also tried setting the contentView background color to clearColor

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
}
```

Also, I've tried to set it again in my VC file

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("header") as? CustomTableViewHeader ?? CustomTableViewHeader(reuseIdentifier: "header")
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        header.titleLabel.text = "custom-text"
        header.delegate = self
        return header
    }
```

Also, I've set the tableviewcell's background to transparent too

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            cell.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
}
```

But no matter what I do, the background of the headerview will not be transparent.

[image]

EDIT: I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118178/custom-uitableview-header-set-background-colour-fail) about the same problem here on SO, but implementing the proposed solution, isn't working

```
 header.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

Comment: It's true that the header footer view's colour cannot be set to clear colour. In fact you cannot change it to any colour. You need to add a UIView as a subview in it and set its background colour to whatever you want.

Comment: We can change it to other colours, but clearColor isn't working.

Comment: You are loading your custom header View from xib?

Comment: No, I'm using code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change the background color to your headerView directly instead of change the color of your headerView.contentView, for me works this example

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return view
    }
```

So change your code in the  `public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` method to this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("header") as? CustomTableViewHeader ?? CustomTableViewHeader(reuseIdentifier: "header")
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        header.titleLabel.text = "custom-text"
        header.delegate = self
        return header
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Earlier I had set background colour to clearColot but it is throws a deprecation error in the console and no it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user6083088 can you please, share your custom header creation process? I mean from xib? from storyboard?, if you share more info I can help you better